# Format Bot messages to Facebook Messenger

Tags: c#, facebook-messenger, botframework

How does one go about formatting messages that the bot sends to the Facebook channel? It doesnt support markdown and there are character limits on the messages.

It also looks like you cannot send images.

so how do you go about formatting the messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [documentation](http://docs.botframework.com/connector/message-actions/#navtitle) for Attachments, Cards and Actions.

Comment: doesnt seem to fully work but I got something. Thanks

Comment: Did you suceed to send images?